# What's the difference between IIS_IUSRS and IUSR?

Tags: iis, web-config

What's the difference between IIS_IUSRS and IUSRS? When I granted permissions for IUSR to web.config it worked, but not when I granted permissions to IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: "IIS_IUSRS", the request user for the ASP page that instatiate your COM object (if it is anonymous, use "IUSRS")  http://forums.iis.net/t/1019895.aspx?IIS+7+cannot+access+32+bit+COM+dll+through+COM+service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation, [Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis), from Microsoft explains it well.

> In summary, IIS 7 and above offer the following:
>
> - The IUSR built-in account replaces the IUSR_MachineName account.
> - The IIS_IUSRS built-in group replaces the IIS_WPG group.

One thing I noticed is that in order to download pdf file from a url, I need to set security permission to iis_iusrs, not iusr.

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?